# Customize series point labels value of a DevExpress chart control

Tags: c#, .net, charts, devexpress

I would like to customize every series point values with a property obtained from the very same data source that is bound to the chart. To illustrate my problem I'll use the same example as DevExpress does in their [website](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument7787) for chart data binding:

```
public class Record {
    int id, age;
    string name;
    public Record(int id, string name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int ID {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public string Name {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public int Age {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }
}
```

To fill the chart it uses the following block of code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Create a list. 
    ArrayList listDataSource = new ArrayList();

    // Populate the list with records. 
    listDataSource.Add(new Record(1, "Jane", 19));
    listDataSource.Add(new Record(2, "Joe", 30));
    listDataSource.Add(new Record(3, "Bill", 15));
    listDataSource.Add(new Record(4, "Michael", 42));

    // Bind the chart to the list. 
    ChartControl myChart = chartControl1;
    myChart.DataSource = listDataSource;
    
    // Create a series, and add it to the chart. 
    Series series1 = new Series("My Series", ViewType.Bar);
    myChart.Series.Add(series1);

    // Adjust the series data members. 
    series1.ArgumentDataMember = "name";
    series1.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "age" });

    // Access the view-type-specific options of the series. 
    ((BarSeriesView)series1.View).ColorEach = true;
    series1.LegendPointOptions.Pattern = "{A}";
}
```

The resulting chart of the code is:

[image: Resulting chart]

My question is, how could I use for example the property `ID` to add extra information for every serie label points? (e.g {ID + " - " + Age}) In the previous graph we would get these label data points: "1 - 19", "2 - 30", "3 - 15" and "4 - 42".

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use the `CustomDrawSeriesPoint` of your chart control, here is how :

```
private void chartControl1_CustomDrawSeriesPoint(object sender, CustomDrawSeriesPointEventArgs e)
{
     // Get the value of your point (Age in your case)
     var pointValue = e.SeriesPoint.Values[0];

     // You can get the argument text using e.SeriesPoint.Argument
     // Set the label text of your point
     e.LabelText = "value is " + pointValue;
}
```

A link that may help : [Click me](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument6816)

Comment: Please, read the question again and pay attention to what I wanna obtain. It's not just adding "value is" before each point, for this purpose I'd just use  `LegendPointOptions.Pattern`.

Comment: Yes, I know, for this I mentioned that you can get the point argument (the record name) and using it to get the Id of your record, and concatinate the two (id and age) to get your desired label. if there is two record with the same name, you can iterate through the point values.

Comment: Well, assuming I'm using the `Age` property as ValueMember (and Integer) it will never be valid for a unique value in a Dictionary and iterating won't help either. At the same time, if any unique id is used as a ValueMember, it will enable the dictionary solution but the chart would have those id's as values so the value itself would have to be modified as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the code this would be done from inside the `Record` object.

That Age parameter is an integer, and matches the chart label as well.  To change that label, change what you are referring to.

Make a new property withing the Record object that looks something like this:

```
public string ChartLabel
{  get { return String.Format("{0} - {1}", ID, Age); } }
```

its a get only property...then you would change the chart code like so:

```
series1.ArgumentDataMember = "name";
series1.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "ChartLabel" });
```

That should change what is displayed in the chart.

Comment: That would'n work since the type of the `LineSeriesView` chart value data member isn't compatible with the numeric scale.

Answer (score 0):

Use LegendPoint options it brings both argument and value in the legend text.

series1.LegendPointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;